# Intersection multiplicity with a line of projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

In Shafarevich´s Example 4.7 in page 244 (Basic Algebraic Geometry), one finds the following.

[image]

I have two questions:

**1.-** Why $\sum k_i deg C_i=m-1$? He defines the degree of a of a projective variety of dimension $n$ as $E^n$, where $E$ is the divisor given by a hyperplane, but I don't see why is this related to the degree of this (or any) $E$.

**2.-** Why $EL=1$? That $L$ is a line doesn't explain much to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first question is just the generalized Bezout theorem. I'm honestly a little stumped why saying that $L$ is a line is enough to justify $EL=1$ - I don't have this book, what material has been covered recently which might be related?

Comment: @KReiser Can you extend a bit on this generalisation of Bezout theorem? I think both questions are related to it. On the other hand, this example is immediately after the example of $E^n$, for $E$ the divisor given by hyperplane section of a variety $X$, that motivates the definition of degree of $X$ (without mentioning to the eq. of $X$). Before that, invariance of intersection number by changing divisors by linear eq. divisors, so one can define intersection numbers if the divisors are not in general position. Before that only basic things.

The book is available online in some webpages.